# Problems using `scale_size_manual` in plotnine

Tags: python, categorical-data, plotnine

I'm trying to use plotnine to build a plot with points sized based on their a classification 1-4.

In the MWE below, I've constructed a test dataset that matches mine.

```
from plotnine import *
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

a = pd.DataFrame(data={'a':4*list(range(4)), 'x':np.random.random(16), 'y':np.random.random(16)})

ggplot(a, aes(x='x', y='y', size='a')) + geom_point() + scale_size_manual(values=(3,3,3,3))
```

However, when I run the code, I get the following message:

> TypeError: Continuous value supplied to discrete scale

Thinking that the problem was that the `a` column was non-categorical, I tried the following MWE:

```
from plotnine import *
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

a = pd.DataFrame(data={'a':4*list(range(4)), 'x':np.random.random(16), 'y':np.random.random(16)})

a['a'] = a['a'].astype('category')

ggplot(a, aes(x='x', y='y', size='a')) + geom_point() + scale_size_manual(values=(3,3,3,3))
```

However, this gives the error message:

> ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer

In R's ggplot (which plotnine attempts to mirror), the following

```
library(ggplot2)
a = data.frame(a=rep(1:4,4), x=runif(16), y=runif(16))
ggplot(a, aes(x=x, y=y, size=a)) + geom_point() + scale_size_manual(values=c(3,3,3,3))
```

gives the familiar message

> Error: Continuous value supplied to discrete scale

Introducing a factor solves the issue:

```
library(ggplot2)
a   = data.frame(a=rep(1:4,4), x=runif(16), y=runif(16))
a$a = factor(a$a)
ggplot(a, aes(x=x, y=y, size=a)) + geom_point() + scale_size_manual(values=c(3,3,3,3))
```

So plotnine seems to be treating categorical information slightly differently from ggplot.

How can I get plotnine to do what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question was recently answered on [github](https://github.com/has2k1/plotnine/issues/108#issuecomment-358184924) and turns out to be a bug stemming from how plotnine interfaces with numpy.

You can avoid the problem with:

```
... + scale_size_manual(values=(3,3,3,3), na_value=-1)
```

Comment: Thanks! A [commit](https://github.com/has2k1/plotnine/commit/232cd592d17a5362723201e4c313faa38c2a8ae3) just went up fixing the problem. That'll probably be in the next release of plotnine.